# How to access element id from another page using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to access an element id of an HTML page from another page. I have seen other solutions but none have worked so far.

For example, if this is One.html

```
<input id="a" type="text"></input>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

I am trying to access the element id 'a' from Two.html to get the value that has been inputted using `

```
var thing = document.getElementById('a').value;
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "the value is" + " " + thing;
```

Comment: not from your current web page?

Comment: only under very limited conditions can pages talk to each other so we need more details before we can help you

Comment: Is two.html ever loaded into your browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
you can use localStorage 
for example in firstpage.html you save data with
var thing = document.getElementById('a').value;
localStorage.something = thing ; 
then in your seconpage.html you can use it by
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=localStorage.something;
```

Comment: Do I add this in the first or second HTML page? And if it is the first page then how do I access localstorage from the second page?

Answer (score 1):

sorry I don't have enough reputation to leave this as a comment but just a heads up, input tags are standalone tags.

```
Example: 
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="a" />
  </body>
```

Comment: Thanks! I did not know that!